# call my own extended jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I looked at this example in this link and I have a problem:
http://jqueryui.com/widget/

It works fine in this form:

```
$(function() { ....});
```

But if I try to use it in a file which I created this way:

```
var Manager = Class.extend({  // the same as prototype - I used class.js
    init: function () {},
    setupPage : function(options){
        $.widget('custom.colorize', {   //here I receive widget is unidentified
            shape: function () {        //just example
                this.x = 0;
                this.y = 0;
                this.w = 1;             //default width and height?
                this.h = 1;
                this.fill = '#444444';
            }
        });
    }
})
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Are you getting an "$.widget is not a function" error? It's probably because jQuery UI hasn't been loaded yet.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell the jQuery UI lib hasn't loaded when you define your class. You could either put the Manager class definition between

```
$(function() { .... });
```

Or you could rearrange your script tags so the jQuery UI is loaded before your class creation  script is loaded (I'd suggest the latter).

Comment: jquery ui run before my script

Comment: Is the setupPage function called somewhere on your page?